# Stored procedure optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my application I am using the below stored procedure, but it is taking a long time to execute. Both tables contain millions of records. Please guide me to optimize this procedure. I have searched a lot but not found any better way.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchReportAdminPanel]
 @UserName nvarchar(max),
 @FromDate datetime,            
 @ToDate datetime,            
 @RecepientNumber nvarchar(max),            
 @Status nvarchar(max),            
 @SenderId nvarchar(max),  
 @PanelMasterId BIGINT = 1,
 @PageIndex INT = 1,        
 @PageSize INT = 10,        
 @RecordCount INT OUTPUT
 WITH RECOMPILE        
AS                      
BEGIN          
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SkipPageRank INT = (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize ;

SELECT temp.*,um.usr_Mobile_No as UserName INTO  #Results FROM 
( 
 SELECT XML_Id, Temp_Id, RIGHT(Mobile_number,10) as Recepient, Message_Text as Text,    
        Coalesce(Message_Status, 'Sent') as Status, CreatedDate,DeliveryDate,User_Id     
 FROM  Table1 xmd WITH (NOLOCK)            
 WHERE (xmd.CreatedDate between @FromDate AND @ToDate) and 
    (RIGHT(xmd.Mobile_number,10) = @RecepientNumber OR @RecepientNumber = '') and           
    (Coalesce(xmd.Message_Status, 'Sent') = @Status OR @Status = '') and            
    (xmd.Sender_Id = @SenderId OR @SenderId = '')   
 UNION ALL
 SELECT XML_Id, Temp_Id, RIGHT(Mobile_number,10) as Recepient, Message_Text as Text,    
        Coalesce(Message_Status, 'Sent') as Status, CreatedDate,DeliveryDate,User_Id   
 FROM  Table2 xmd WITH (NOLOCK)            
 WHERE (xmd.CreatedDate between @FromDate AND @ToDate) and 
    (RIGHT(xmd.Mobile_number,10) = @RecepientNumber OR @RecepientNumber = '')   and         
    (Coalesce(xmd.Message_Status, 'Sent') = @Status OR @Status = '') and            
    (xmd.Sender_Id = @SenderId OR @SenderId = '')
) temp INNER JOIN Table3 um WITH (NOLOCK) on temp.User_Id = um.usr_Id
WHERE
    (um.usr_Mobile_No = @UserName OR @UserName = '') and
    (um.PanelMasterId=@PanelMasterId)

   SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results        

   select * from #Results
   ORDER BY XML_Id DESC    
   OFFSET @SkipPageRank ROWS
   FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

    DROP TABLE #Results        
END
```

[image: Below is the query execution plan]

Comment: you should merge your 2 accounts: http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/81564/mayur-rathod and http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/81562/mayur-rathod . See http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts .

Comment: First do not use * . Name all your columns!

Comment: Optimize the two selects.  Post those two query plans.

Comment: Also [stop using the `sp_` prefix](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) and [be aware that `WITH RECOMPILE` has some side effects that are avoided by using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on individual statements](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of this term

```
(Coalesce(xmd.Message_Status, 'Sent') = @Status OR @Status = '')
```

in your inner WHERE clauses is non SARG-able, so no index can be used. Change both occurrences as shown below, to make this term SARG-able:

```
(xmd.Message_Status  = @Status 
    OR (xmd.Message_Status is NULL AND @Status = 'Sent')
    OR @Status = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

try pulling condition in the temp where up into the joins
filter early when you can

```
SELECT temp.*,um.usr_Mobile_No as UserName INTO  #Results FROM 
( 
 SELECT XML_Id, Temp_Id, RIGHT(Mobile_number,10) as Recepient, Message_Text as Text,    
        Coalesce(Message_Status, 'Sent') as Status, CreatedDate,DeliveryDate,User_Id     
 FROM  Table1 xmd WITH (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN Table3 um WITH (NOLOCK) 
        on Table1.User_Id = um.usr_Id 
       and (um.usr_Mobile_No = @UserName OR @UserName = '') 
       and (um.PanelMasterId=@PanelMasterId)            
 WHERE (xmd.CreatedDate between @FromDate AND @ToDate) and 
       (RIGHT(xmd.Mobile_number,10) = @RecepientNumber OR @RecepientNumber = '') and           
       (Coalesce(xmd.Message_Status, 'Sent') = @Status OR @Status = '') and            
       (xmd.Sender_Id = @SenderId OR @SenderId = '')   
 UNION ALL
 SELECT XML_Id, Temp_Id, RIGHT(Mobile_number,10) as Recepient, Message_Text as Text,    
        Coalesce(Message_Status, 'Sent') as Status, CreatedDate,DeliveryDate,User_Id   
 FROM  Table2 xmd WITH (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN Table3 um WITH (NOLOCK) 
        on Table2.User_Id = um.usr_Id 
       and (um.usr_Mobile_No = @UserName OR @UserName = '') 
       and (um.PanelMasterId=@PanelMasterId)            
 WHERE (xmd.CreatedDate between @FromDate AND @ToDate) and 
       (RIGHT(xmd.Mobile_number,10) = @RecepientNumber OR @RecepientNumber = '')   and         
       (Coalesce(xmd.Message_Status, 'Sent') = @Status OR @Status = '') and            
       (xmd.Sender_Id = @SenderId OR @SenderId = '')
) temp
```